# String is not interpolated correct when using convert sub process

Tags: node.js, imagemagick-convert, google-zx

I am using node 14 and https://github.com/google/zx for creating images with text.
The string is interpolated but shows a strange format in the image.

The sub process is called like this:

```
let annotation = `${title}\n ${date.mtime.toISOString()}`
await $`convert ${frameImage} -gravity south -fill white -pointsize 36 -annotate +0+10 "${annotation}" ${frameImage}`
```

The result shows like this on the image:

```
$'Title 
2021-02-03T07:05:01.00Z'
```

I would expect it renders without the `$` and `'` like:

```
Title 
2021-02-03T07:05:01.00Z
```

Example image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the quotes in the command, just omit them and then the output is as desired.

```
await $`convert ${frameImage} -gravity south -fill white -pointsize 36 -annotate +0+10 ${annotation} ${frameImage}`
```

Zx takes care of escaping automatically so adding the quotes is kind of double:
https://github.com/google/zx/blob/main/docs/quotes.md